# Checking to see if a DATETIME was 14 days ago

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

What I'm trying to do is query a table in the database so that I can send a Welcome email 14 days after they have activated their account...

Once I successfully send the email, I will then set the flag = 0 so that the email isn't sent again in the future.

I don't know how to compare the `activation_date` DATETIME to the 14 day period...

Comment: Have a look at `DATEDIFF` function: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx  You will be using it to calculate the difference between **current date** and your `activation_date`

Answer (score 1):

you can use datediff:

if the datediff to the activation = 14, select the row:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
WHERE 14 = DATEDIFF(activation_date, $today)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your activation_date to DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 day) in the query.

Comment: Can you write a light example?

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE activation_date<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 day) AND flag=1;

Comment: I dont want to DATE_SUB ... I want to take activation_date and ADD 14 days to it... no? `SELECT * FROM bid_tag WHERE activation_date = DATE_ADD(activation_date, INTERVAL 14 day) AND active = 1 AND msg_welcome = 0`

Comment: I thought that activation_date was the time that the user activated their account and that the function would be ran 14+ days after. The DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 day) gets the time 14 days ago so my query should get all records that are older than 14 days. Your where clause will never select anything since it always tries to do "WHERE x=x+14", basically. Gotta involve NOW() somehow since you want 14 days earlier than now.

Answer (score 0):

Use datediff() function, here is an example to see how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/7851

```
Select '2013-04-10', 

case 
when datediff( now() , '2013-04-10' ) = 14 
then 'Send eMail' 
else 'Don''t send eMail' 
end 

as SendeMail

UNION ALL 


Select '2013-04-11', 

case 
when datediff( now() , '2013-04-11' ) = 14 
then 'Send eMail' 
else 'Don''t send eMail' 
end 

as SendeMail

UNION ALL


Select '2013-04-15' , 

case 
when datediff( now() , '2013-04-15' ) = 14 
then 'Send eMail' 
else 'Don''t send eMail' 
end 

as SendeMail
```

Of course you can use it in a WHERE Statement ...

```
WHERE datediff( now() , '2013-04-11' ) = 14
```

Use `now()` function to get the current date. My example date (2013-04-11) should be replaces with your `activation_date` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date_sub function in a where clause

```
where activation_date > date_sub(now() ,interval 14 day) and flag <> 0
```

sample code [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40e92/2/0)

Comment: What does the `<>` operator mean?

Comment: <> means not equal (same as !=)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW() , activation_date ) = 14 AND active = 1 AND msg_welcome = 0
```

This is the query that I needed! Thanks a lot guys... just had to modify your advice a little.